# Is there a general `filetype=code` for Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to apply a Vim `autocmd` to all source code files -- for instance,

```
autocmd FileType <code> :set tw=80
```

Can I do this without listing all the different extensions exhaustively, like

```
autocmd FileType ruby, python, python3, java ... :set tw=80
```

What's the best way to do this? Is there some general `FileType` or `Syntax` that Vim recognizes inside any source file?

Comment: Would it be easier to make `tw=80` the default for all file types, and set it to something else for another (presumably smaller) set of file types?

Comment: Generally, yes, but `:au FileType * ...` can be useful to globally override particular settings in filetype plugins. I do it for `'indentkeys'` for example.

Comment: I don't remember this as a possibility with vim but what you're looking for is the vim equivalent to Emacs' [prog-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgMode).  Maybe this will help with searches.

Comment: What if you only set `tw=80` if syntax highlighting is enabled? I'm no vim script expert but it sounds like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` to match all occurrences of an event. In your case:

```
:autocmd FileType * command
```

See `:help autocmd-patterns` and `:help file-pattern`.

Comment: This would also fire for files which are not necessarily source code, which is the distinction I think @Sasgorilla is asking for.

Comment: Oh, I see. If so, then I guess the OP will need to clarify requirements.